# raster sytling multiband rendering 0=nodata

Tags: qgis, style, rendering, multi-band, stack

Is there any way to set the pixel value 0 to nodata of a raster stack in the multiband rendering type in QGIS?

I remember that it is possible to check a box in arcgis for that, so maybe i just oversee it in QGIS?

It is pretty annoying to convert all 0 values to nodata just for the style.

The min value for the rgb bands should start at the real min and ignore the 0 values

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can set the transparency for the raster value of 0 (Zero) to 100%. You can do that using layer properties -> transparency as you can see below:

[image]

Then add values and write 0 For Red, Green and Blue colors and set the transparency to 100, which is the default.

You also nee to the change the display of the RGB colors as follows:

1- Zoom to the target area

2- Choose Mean -/+ standard deviation

3- Accuracy -> Check Actual

4- Load

[image]

Comment: still the problem with styling. I updated the question above to make it more clear. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I updated my answer

Comment: but this anyway would set just a transparency to the 0 values but would not ignore it what results in wrong colors for an rgb image. Still the styling would start at 0 to max and not from the first value >0.

Comment: I updated my answer again.

Comment: this doesnt answer my last comment. Still the min value of r g and b band starts at 0. The transparancy method just as the name indicates put a transparancy to the 0 values

Comment: ArcGIS also does not alter the pixel value of 0, it is just give a transparent color when you check the box of Display RGB color of 0,0,0 to no color.